# AlertDialog does not show onclick

Tags: android

AlertDialog does not show onclick.

When you longclick on a button, there should be a dialog that pops up, but it doesn't. The longClicklistener is accessed, but the dialog still does not come up.

```
    // Set Reset Button
    resetBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
    resetBtn.setOnLongClickListener(new Button.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialogWrapper.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialogWrapper.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.MAIN_MENU_RESET_ALERT_YES), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.MAIN_MENU_RESET_ALERT_RESULT_YES), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });                alertDialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.MAIN_MENU_RESET_ALERT_NO), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.MAIN_MENU_RESET_ALERT_RESULT_NO), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            // Showing Alert Message
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **alertDialog.show()**

```
// Set Reset Button 
resetBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.resetButton); 
resetBtn.setOnLongClickListener(new Button.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        AlertDialogWrapper.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialogWrapper.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.MAIN_MENU_RESET_ALERT_YES), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Write your code here to invoke YES event 
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.MAIN_MENU_RESET_ALERT_RESULT_YES), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            } 
        });                  
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.MAIN_MENU_RESET_ALERT_NO), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.MAIN_MENU_RESET_ALERT_RESULT_NO), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.cancel();
            } 
        }); 
        /*** Showing Alert Message ***/
        alertDialog.show();
        return true; 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot

```
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Set Reset Button
    resetBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
    resetBtn.setOnLongClickListener(new Button.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialogWrapper.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialogWrapper.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.MAIN_MENU_RESET_ALERT_YES), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.MAIN_MENU_RESET_ALERT_RESULT_YES), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });                alertDialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.MAIN_MENU_RESET_ALERT_NO), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.MAIN_MENU_RESET_ALERT_RESULT_NO), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
alertDialog.show();
            // Showing Alert Message
            return true;
        }
    });
```

you need to call show()

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
 alertDialog.show();
```

before `return true`.

That is,

```
  // Showing Alert Message
  alertDialog.show(); // code to show alert message [Missed]
  return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed main line in code for showing dialog... just add below line

```
// Showing Alert Message
  alertDialog.show(); 
  return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `AlertDialogWrapper.Builder` to `AlertDialog.Builder`. And before `return true;` call `alertDialog.create();` and `alertDialog.show()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing alertDialog.show() and see the example for alert dialog box on long click

```
SingleButtton.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // Creating alert Dialog with one Button

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new  
        AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Welcome to Android Application");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new 
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
                    {
                        // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
        return true;

    }
});


btnAlertTwoBtns.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // Creating alert Dialog with two Buttons

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                        // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
        return true;

    }
});

btnAlertThreeBtns.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // Creating alert Dialog with three Buttons

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                AlertDialogActivity.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Save File...");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to save this file?");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.save);

        // Setting Positive Yes Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        // User pressed Cancel button. Write Logic Here
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "You clicked on YES",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        // Setting Negative No Button... Neutral means in between yes and cancel button
        alertDialog.setNeutralButton("NO",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        // User pressed No button. Write Logic Here
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
        // Setting Positive "Cancel" Button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        // User pressed Cancel button. Write Logic Here
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "You clicked on Cancel",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
         return true;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You forget to do this......

 AlertDialog aD = alertDialog.create();

    try {
        aD.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```